# Select columns of a matrix with minimum number of NaN values in the rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have the following matrix.

```
Data = [
    672 741 642 NaN 826 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    589 371 237 539 555 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    529 699 593 578 653 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    552 654 337 473 697 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    512 421 479 553 346 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    325 348 356 295 337 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    263 369 303 338 395 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    503 472 372 428 563 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    464 NaN 444 286 436 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    382 208 264 196 331 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    416 431 405 443 491 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    370 414 351 137 405 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    631 622 597 500 555 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    368 373 697 538 550 NaN NaN NaN 384;
    467 446 463 361 406 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
    398 457 461 376 469 NaN NaN NaN NaN
];
```

With the function (that I am looking for)

```
c = number of columns desired
[idx_col] = select_cols(Data,3);
```

I would like the indexes of columns of Data that have the maximum number of rows without NaNs.

For ex:

```
    c = 3; % number of columns desired
    [idx_col] = select_cols(Data,3);
idx_col{1} = 1,3,5 since they do not have NaN elements.

c=4
idx_col{1} = 1,2,3,5 (there is only row 9 with NaN)
and
idx_col{2} = 1,3,4,5 (there is only row 1 with NaN)

c=2
idx_col{1} = 1,3
and
idx_col{2} = 1,5
and
idx_col{3} = 3,5
```

Comment: And in case of ties? For example c=7. Or c=2

Comment: @AnderBiguri I added the example c=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Data = [
672 741 642 NaN 826 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
589 371 237 539 555 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
529 699 593 578 653 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
552 654 337 473 697 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
512 421 479 553 346 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
325 348 356 295 337 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
263 369 303 338 395 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
503 472 372 428 563 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
464 NaN 444 286 436 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
382 208 264 196 331 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
416 431 405 443 491 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
370 414 351 137 405 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
631 622 597 500 555 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
368 373 697 538 550 NaN NaN NaN 384;
467 446 463 361 406 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
398 457 461 376 469 NaN NaN NaN NaN
];

c = 4;

% end of input
[B,IX] =sort(sum(isnan(Data)));

how_many_nans = B(c);

% include all columns with nans less then maximum number  of nans detected

constant_columns = IX(find(B<how_many_nans));

% columns with exactly maximum nans dhould be taken as combination

border_columns = IX(find(B == how_many_nans));

k = c - length(constant_columns);

C = nchoosek(border_columns,k);

% concatenate
desired_matrix = [repmat(constant_columns,size(C,1),1) C];

% turn into cells
desired_cell={};
for i = 1:size(desired_matrix,1)
    desired_cell{i} = desired_matrix(i,:)
end
```

Comment: Hi, NaN in the rows should  be considered together

Comment: Ok I edited the answer to exactly match your specs, but IMAO you could have done it yourself.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I tried by myself and added an answer above...it produces the same results...can you check please whether makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = [
672 741 642 NaN 826 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
589 371 237 539 555 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
529 699 593 578 653 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
552 654 337 473 697 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
512 421 479 553 346 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
325 348 356 295 337 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
263 369 303 338 395 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
503 472 372 428 563 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
464 NaN 444 286 436 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
382 208 264 196 331 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
416 431 405 443 491 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
370 414 351 137 405 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
631 622 597 500 555 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
368 373 697 538 550 NaN NaN NaN 384;
467 446 463 361 406 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
398 457 461 376 469 NaN NaN NaN NaN
];

c = 4;

combos = combntns(1:size(Data,2),c);
howmanyrows_notnan = zeros(size(combos,1),1);
for i = 1 : size(combos,1)
    howmanyrows_notnan(i) = numel(find(all(~isnan(Data(:,combos(i,:))), 2)==1));
end
maxval = max(howmanyrows_notnan);
idx = find(howmanyrows_notnan == maxval);

IDX = combos(idx,:);
```

Comment: Completely legit, the only thing is that there is this for loop that would be quite slow on larger inputs. In my answer I have a loop, but this is only used to turn the matrix to cell, which is probably not necessary, I put it there just to match your specification.